# Inequality for bounded locally integrable functions

Tags: real-analysis, lebesgue-integral, integral-inequality

> $\textbf{The Problem:}$ Let $f\geq 0$ be a bounded function and $E\subset\mathbb R^d$ have finite measure. Prove that there exists $R>0$ such that for all $0<r<R$ we have
>   $$\int_{E}f(x)dx\leq 2\int_{E}\left(\frac{1}{\vert B(x,r)\vert}\int_{B(x,r)}f(y)dy\right)dx.$$
>   Here $B(x,r)$ denotes the open ball of radius $r$ centered at $x$.

I will use the following $\color{blue}{\text{Theorem}}$ from page $106$ in Stein and Shakarchi's Real Analysis: If $f$ is locally integrable in $\mathbb R^d$ then we have for almost every $x\in\mathbb R^d$ that
$$\lim\limits_{\vert B\vert\to0}\frac{1}{\vert B\vert }\int_{B}f(y)dy=f(x),\quad x\in B,$$
where $B$ is a ball containig $x$.

$\textbf{My Attempt:}$ Suppose for a contradiction that such $R>0$ does not exist. Then given $R>0$ there is some $0<r<R$ such that
$$\infty>\int_{E}f(x)dx> 2\int_{E}\left(\frac{1}{\vert B(x,r)\vert}\int_{B(x,r)}f(y)dy\right)dx.$$
In particular, this means that for almost every $x\in E$ we must have
$$\infty>\frac{f(x)}{2}>\frac{1}{\vert B(x,r)\vert}\int_{B(x,r)}f(y)dy.$$
And since by the assumption that $f\geq0$ and bounded, we have that
$$\frac{1}{\vert B(x,r)\vert}\int_{B(x,r)}f(y)dy\geq \frac{1}{\vert B(x,p)\vert}\int_{B(x,p)}f(y)dy$$ for all $0<p<r,$ we have a contradiction of the $\color{blue}{\text{Theorem}}$.

---

Is the above proof correct? Any feedback is welcomed. If my proof is incorrect, please do not provide a solution, only hints.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Not seeing how the first inequality in your proof follows from the [Lebesgue Differentiation Theorem](*https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lebesgue_differentiation_theorem*).  Can you include the statement of the Theorem as you have it in your sources?  (Besides, you didn't specify what $B$ stands for, though one can guess.)

Comment: @avs Thank your for pointing that out. I edited the post. If it remains unclear, please tell me.

Comment: I think the Theorem implies that for almost every $x$ there is $R$, but not that there is an $R$ for almost every $x$. Also, formally $f$ doesn't have to be defined on the whole $B(r, x)$, so you can't integrate over it.

Comment: Are you sure that $B(x, r)$ is just a ball of radius $r$ **containing** $x$, as opposed to **centered at** $x$?

Comment: @avs That's the statement in the book, though I understand your concern, and I have it myself.

Comment: @avs I thought I could put $R=\inf\{p\}$ where $p$ is the radius needed for each particular $x$ to work out the inequality. Would that be correct?

Comment: What if that $\inf$ is $0$?

Comment: @avs Good point. But in that case the measure of the ball is zero, so we are dividing by zero, which would be a problem. Shoud I put then $0<p.$?

Comment: No, it doesn't mean we are dividing by zero.  Even a set of strictly positive numbers can have infimum zero.:)  But, I think I figured out how to guide you.  I'll put it in an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't understand the proof you gave. Here's a hint for another approach: It's enough to show

$$\lim_{r\to 0^+}\int_{E}\left(\frac{1}{\vert B(x,r)\vert}\int_{B(x,r)}f(y)dy\right)dx = \int_{E}f(x)dx .$$

Call the function inside the parentheses $g_r(x).$ Then $g_r(x)\to f(x)$ as $r\to 0^+$ for a.e. $x\in E.$ Apply the DCT ...

Answer (score 1):

If some quantity $M(r)$ tends toward a strictly positive quantity $f(x)$ as $r \rightarrow 0$, then for $r$ small enough, $M(r)$ will be so close to $f(x)$ as to be $> f(x)/2$.

Comment: Sorry for not seen it yet, my only concern is how to get the $R>0$ that works for almost every $x$?

Comment: In the Theorem, does the radius of the ball $B$ depend on $x$?  I can't determine that from the Theorem statement you posted.

Comment: I read over the book and seems to me thaf it does not depend on $x$.

Comment: I think you need to use the fact that $E$ has finite measure.  For every $R$ and every $\epsilon > 0$, then, there exist finitely many balls of radius $R$ such that their union covers "nearly all of $E$"; i.e., a subset of $E$ such that the remaining--uncovered--part of $E$ has measure $\leq \epsilon$.